# config error in Qtile (Tiling Window Manager)

Tags: python, linux, config, archlinux, window-managers

im trying to configure qtile by looking at a reference config from DistroTube(Youtube)'s gitlab : https://gitlab.com/dwt1/dotfiles/-/blob/master/.config/qtile/config.py

im getting an error while adding this

```
##### BAR #####

def init_widgets_screen():
widgets_screen = init_widgets_list()
return widgets_screen

def init_screens() :
return [Screen(top=bar.Bar(widgets=init_widgets_screen(), opacity=0.95, size=20))

if __name__ in ["config", "__main__"]:
screens = init_screens()
widgets_list = init_widgets_list()
widget_screen = init_widgets_screen()
```

he is using 3 monitors, and im trying to install this on my laptop so just one screen

( the needed part in the reference link starts on line 555)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it might just be a white spacing issue. You need to indent each function body. There's also an extra white space before the colon in the `init_screens` definition (though I think this is actually legal python).

In the case that the lack of indenting was just from copy and pasting into stack overflow, it would help if you could run `qtile` in a terminal and copy the output/error here.

```py
##### BAR #####

def init_widgets_screen():
    widgets_screen = init_widgets_list()
    return widgets_screen

def init_screens():
    return [Screen(top=bar.Bar(widgets=init_widgets_screen(), opacity=0.95, size=20))

if __name__ in ["config", "__main__"]:
    screens = init_screens()
    widgets_list = init_widgets_list()
    widget_screen = init_widgets_screen()
```

## Edit after clarification

Your config file has defines the `init_widgets_list` function between line 114 and 317 and it looks something like this:

```py
def init_widgets_list():
  widgets_list = [
    [
      widget.Sep(
        linewidth = 0,
        padding = 6,
        foreground = colors[2],
        background = colors[0]
      ),
      # ...
      widget.Systray(
        background=colors[0],
        padding = 5
      ),
    ],
  ]

  return widgets_list
```

You are wrapping the list of widgets in another list and qtile is expecting a flat list of widgets. To fix it you need to remove one set of square brackets.

```py
def init_widgets_list():
  widgets_list = [
    widget.Sep(
      linewidth = 0,
      padding = 6,
      foreground = colors[2],
      background = colors[0]
    ),
    # ...
    widget.Systray(
      background=colors[0],
      padding = 5
    ),
  ]

  return widgets_list
```

Comment: i tried running qtile through terminal and i got (https://imgur.com/gm8zikZ)
so i added a line from DistroTube's config - 

prompt = "{0}@{1}: ".format(os.environ["USER"], socket.gethostname())   

i ran qtile again in terminal then i got this - (https://imgur.com/3iHy6DA)

Comment: The error you mention comes from [here](https://github.com/qtile/qtile/blob/5bd8e57f78b72ed9de4d10bf51af6db51561d794/libqtile/bar.py#L197). It looks like your `init_widgets_list` function might be returning a list containing another list when it expects `Widget`s.

Comment: here is my config if u can help me - https://pastebin.com/m3FYZ6N2

Comment: See updated answer - also here's an fixed version of the config you sent https://pastebin.com/rRRWv290

Comment: aah, i must have missed it because i copied it from DistroTube's config. i will try it and get back to you.